# How to call a constructor with an empty initiailizer_list in c++17?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, initializer-list, stdinitializerlist

Consider this code:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){cout<<"empty"<<endl;}
    Foo(initializer_list<int>){cout<<"init_list"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Foo(); // empty
    Foo{}; // empty
    Foo({}); // init_list for c++14, empty for c++17
}
```

I am wondering why they behave differently between C++14 and C++17, and how to construct a `Foo` with an empty `initializer_list` in C++17?

Comment: `Foo{{}}` or `Foo({{}})` works, but it is confusing. In the first view, it seems an init_list nested in an init_list. And it is even more confusing when Foo can take nested init_list (imaging Foo is a json like class). Could that be possible if a modification in class Foo works?

Comment: My c++17 doesn't emit empty for last case
```g++ --std=c++17 ctor.cpp 
./a.out 
empty
empty
init_list
```

Comment: Could I have your g++ version? Mine is 7.5.0

Comment: Seems being fixed since [gcc 8.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dE4uaYTacKQkj71R).